# multiply user input through JTextField with an array of double values

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm very new to Java (and programming in general). I'm working on a program that should accept a double value from user through a JTextField and multiply it with quite a few double values in an array, and display the result in a JTextArea.  A kind of calculator you could say.

Right now, I only see the result of the input multiplied with the last value in the array(0.50) and im sure there's something with my loop, array or something missing, I just cant figure out what.

```
double[] percRM = {0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50};                
double dDouble;
double pFinal;

if(ae.getSource() == pressbutton){
       pDouble = Double.parseDouble(presstext.getText());
        for (int j=0;j<percRM.length;j++){
            pFinal = percRM[j] * pDouble;
        }
            resulttext.setText("The Sum is:" + "\n" + pFinal+ "\t");
      }
```

I also have a JFrame with quite a few buttons. Please tell me if you want me to show my entire code.

And while im here, I wonder how I can add some text next to each value printed, lets say user input is 100, the result will be(example):

```
The sum is:

Week1:
Set1 = 65
Set2 = 75
Set3 = 85
etc.
```

appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `setText(...)` on the JTextArea and doing so after the loop is over. `setText(..)` will erase everything that the JTextArea is currently showing and replace it with your new text -- now what you want. The `append(...)` method just adds new text tot he bottom.

Instead call `append(...)` and do so inside of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {
  double value = doSomeCalculation():
  myTextField.append("result: " + value + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out now. also please see my edit. I have an additional question if you are interested.

Comment: @user2900511: my example already answers the second part. Just append whatever text you need to show.